# Append MUI Autocomplete with Add Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am making an add sales component that requires an add button to add multiple products. I made it working with normal TextField with following code but when added Autocomplete, I am unable. Looking for help.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
 Box,
 TextField,
 Grid,
 InputLabel,
 Tooltip,
 IconButton,
 Autocomplete
} from "@mui/material";
import { Add, Remove } from "@mui/icons-material";

const products = [
 { id: 1, name: "Green Apple" },
 { id: 2, name: "Red Cherry" },
 { id: 3, name: "Strawberry" },
 { id: 4, name: "Ground Apple" },
 { id: 5, name: "Dragon Fruit" },
 { id: 6, name: "White pear" }
];

function AddSale() {
 const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ name: "", qty: "", rate: "" }]);

 // handle input change
 const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
   const { name, value } = e.target;
   const list = [...inputList];
   list[index][name] = value;
   setInputList(list);
 };

 // handle click event of the Remove button
 const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
   const list = [...inputList];
   list.splice(index, 1);
   setInputList(list);
 };

 // handle click event of the Add button
 const handleAddClick = () => {
   setInputList([...inputList, { name: "", qty: "", rate: "" }]);
 };

 return (
   <Grid container spacing={2}>
     <Grid item sx={{ py: 0 }} xs={5}>
       <InputLabel>Select a item*</InputLabel>
     </Grid>
     <Grid item sx={{ py: 0 }} xs={2}>
       <InputLabel>Qty (Piece)*</InputLabel>
     </Grid>
     <Grid item sx={{ py: 0 }} xs={3}>
       <InputLabel>Rate (Rs)*</InputLabel>
     </Grid>
     <Grid item sx={{ py: 0 }} xs={2} />
     {inputList.map((x, i) => {
       return (
         <React.Fragment key={i}>
           <Grid item xs={5}>
             <Autocomplete
               value={x.name}
               onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
               inputValue={x.name}
               onInputChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
               id="select-product"
               options={products}
               disableClearable
               getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
               renderOption={(props, option) => (
                 <li {...props}>{option.name}</li>
               )}
               renderInput={(params) => (
                 <TextField
                   name="name"
                   {...params}
                   placeholder="Select product"
                 />
               )}
             />
           </Grid>
           <Grid item xs={2}>
             <Box>
               <TextField
                 id="sale-qty"
                 name="qty"
                 value={x.qty}
                 onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                 variant="outlined"
                 fullWidth
               />
             </Box>
           </Grid>
           <Grid item xs={3}>
             <Box>
               <TextField
                 id="sale-rate"
                 name="rate"
                 value={x.rate}
                 onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                 variant="outlined"
                 fullWidth
               />
             </Box>
           </Grid>
           <Grid item xs={2} sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
             {inputList.length !== 1 && (
               <Tooltip title="Remove">
                 <IconButton
                   onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}
                   color="error"
                 >
                   <Remove color="error" />
                 </IconButton>
               </Tooltip>
             )}
             {inputList.length - 1 === i && (
               <Tooltip title="Add new">
                 <IconButton onClick={handleAddClick}>
                   <Add />
                 </IconButton>
               </Tooltip>
             )}
           </Grid>
         </React.Fragment>
       );
     })}
   </Grid>
 );
}

export default AddSale;
```

Here is screenshot how it should look like
[image]

Also codesandbox of current state
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-sunset-hxrfy?file=/src/App.js:0-3803